# Azure Container Apps - Service stopping despite minimum replica being 1

Tags: azure, .net-core, worker-service, azure-container-apps

I've got a .NET worker service based on a cron schedule running in a Docker container and pushed up to Azure Container Apps. The schedule is managed within the application itself.

The scaling is set to have a minumum of 1 replica running at all times.

However, we've found that for some reason the application starts up, idles waiting for the schedule trigger for ~20-30 seconds, stops for 2 seconds, starts and idles for ~20-30 seconds again and then doesn't run again for ~5-6 minutes. During the idling time, the job might start if the cron schedule lines up while the process is running.

Is there any way to diagnose why it might be auto-killing the application?

I can't seem to find any logs that show any fatal exceptions or along those lines, and running in other environments (locally, Azure Container Instance etc.) doesn't replicate the behavior. My suspicion is that it's the auto-scaling behavior: Azure is noticing that the process is idle for 20-30 seconds at a time and killing that replica, only for it to spin up again 5 mins later. However, I can't seem to find anything to prove that theory.

I'm aware that other resource types might be better suited (Container Instances, App Service, Functions) though for now I'm stuck with Container Apps.

Answer (score 4):

Found the cause of the issue based on this SO question:
[Azure Container Apps Restarts every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72362826/azure-container-apps-restarts-every-30-seconds)

Turns out, Azure was trying to do health checks on it despite no HTTP ports being exposed. Azure thinking the container is unhealthy, kills and restarts it. Turning off HTTP ingress (and therefore the health checks) solved this issue.