# How to configure backend application on Container Apps

Tags: azure, api, backend, azure-container-apps

everyone.
I'm currently deploying an application via Container apps on Azure. We have one environment with two container instances, backend and frontend. The backend connects with Postgres flexible server and Azure Cache for Redis. However, I always get an error message during system logs of the backend container that goes:

'Startup probe failed: Get \u0022https://{IP ADDRESS}/\u0022: dial tcp {IP ADDRESS}:443: connect: connection refused","Reason":"PodUnhealthy","EventSource":"ContainerAppController"'.
The container keeps restarting and exits after a few tries.

Does anyone know about possible solutions for this issue? Is there a way to view the console logs inside the container and not only system logs? I appreciate any help.

I've seen other posts about it but the solutions haven't worked out for me. The curious thing about it is that the frontend image was deployed without issues and if I use the App Services the backend functions normally, meaning I can access the Swagger of the API. Also, I can see console logs on Web Apps and the container starts without problems. I tried checking environment variables and such but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Container Apps Restarts every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72362826/azure-container-apps-restarts-every-30-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Startup probe failed: Get https://{IP ADDRESS}/: dial tcp {IP ADDRESS}:443: connect: connection refused"

Is your application listening on `443`? the probe is for the health of the application and should be configured to the port the application is listening on.

Also the application must listen on http or http2 plaintext, not https.